# Replace unwanted footer text with empty space

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall

how to replace unwanted footer text?

```
 ---  
This email has been checked for viruses by Avast antivirus software.  
http://www.avast.com
```

html code footer:

```
     <span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br><br><br>---<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br>
This email has been checked for viruses by Avast antivirus software.<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br>
<a href="http://www.avast.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(22, 54, 87); ">
http://www.avast.com</a></span></span>
```

almost done, but I think the code can be placed on one line

```
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = data;
data = data.replace(/---.*/gi, '');
data = data.replace((/(<br>This email has.*).+?/gi, '');
data = data.replace((/(http:\/\/www\.avast\.com)<\/a>?(<br\s*\/?>{2,3})?/gi, '');
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = data;
```

an example found in a forum

```
data = data.replace(/(<br>){2,3}---(<br>This).+?(avast\.com)<\/a>( ---)?/gi, '');
```

the code above will workt in plain html, it won't work with the generated code by WebKit

Comment: *"but I think the code can be placed on one line"* - Why does it need to be on one line? Why do you set innerHTML on the first line when `data` doesn't have a value yet? Are you aware that you are missing a semicolon on the third line? Why can't you get rid of the line server side? Are you aware that the example of the forum uses a `data` variable too, in other words, that that code is incomplete?

Comment: in your example html, what are the last 2 `</span>` for? Are those a mistakeor are they really in your html like that?

Comment: @GolezTrol, see example

data = data.replace(/(<br>){2,3}---(<br>This).+?(avast\.com)<\/a>( ---)?/gi, '');

the semicolon was a bad copy & paste it's just a part of the code:
The code works accept the <br> part won't replace, that's because the WebKit
I think it can be improved
 
 
BTW it's not on a server site but a local program. Thnx for your reply.

Comment: @DelightedD0D they really in the html like that, just edited the post, now you see the beginning as well (the start from 'spam' footer)

Comment: hmm, thats wierd, where are the opening tags for those two spans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex:

```
---.*|<br>\s*This email has.*|<a\b[^>]*>.*?(http:\/\/www\.avast\.com).*?</a>
```

- `---.*` ==> Matches text from: `data.replace(/---.*/gi, '');`
- `<br>\s*This email has.*`  ==> Matches text from: `data.replace((/(<br>This email has.*).+?/gi, '');` //With an correction to match whitespace characters after `<br>` 
  As alternative you could write: `<br>\s*This email has[^<]*` to stop at the end of the line or at the beginning of the next tag.
- `<a\b[^>]*>.*?http:\/\/www\.avast\.com.*?</a>`  ==> Matches the link that contains `"http://www.avast.com"` in the name (link text).
- The | is for matching the alternative regex, if the previous regex didn't match

[Regex Test](https://www.regex101.com/r/uJ7pR3/3)

---

```
result = text.replace(/---.*|<br>\s*This email has.*|<a\b[^>]*>.*?(http:\/\/www\.avast\.com).*?<\/a>/gi, "");
```

Comment: Can you explain what this regex is doing exactly? It doesnt seem to function as expected, see http://affordable-glass.com/test/Screenshot%20at%20Jan%2004%2010-54-28.png

Comment: @DelightedD0D Edited the part for matching the link

Comment: Andie2302, works like a charm!
Thank you, also for explaining the code (puzzle solved)

Contributors thank you as well.

Comment: Ah, ok, I assumed the OP wanted all of the `<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>` muckety-muck gone too

Answer (score 0):

`/(<br>){3}[\s\S]+?avast.com<\/a>/` Should work just fine for you:

1. `(<br>){3}` matches exactly 3 br tags
2. `[\s\S]` matches anything, including line breaks (basically says any character that is a space and any character that is not a space, ie everything)
3. `+` says to match one or more of the previous criteria (any character)
4. `?` says to match as few of the last criteria (any character) as necessary to reach the next criteria
5. `avast.com<\/a>/` match this string exactly

```js
function removeFooter(){

  var elm = document.getElementById('footer');
  elm.innerHTML = elm.innerHTML.replace(/(<br>){3}[\s\S]+?avast.com<\/a>/, "repalced footer text");

}
```

```css
#msgBody{
  height:55px;
  width:300px;
  background-color:#999999;
  margin-top:10px;
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="removeFooter()" value="Remove Footer"/>
<div id="msgBody"></div>
<div id="footer">
<br><br><br>
 <span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br>
  This email has been checked for viruses by Avast antivirus software.
<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><br>
<a href="http://www.avast.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(22, 54, 87); "> http://www.avast.com</a>
</div>
```